# C++ undefined reference to `_Hash_bytes' error for using string as a key in unordered_map

Tags: c++, string, hash, unordered-map

In C++, I am getting undefined reference to `_Hash_bytes' error when I am using string as key in unordered_map.

```cpp
declaration : unordered_map< string, list< pair< string,string>>::iterator> map_;
```

compiler used: `g++ -std=c++11`

The complete error:

```
In function 'std::_Hash_impl::hash(void const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)':
serverdebug.cpp:(.text._ZNSt10_Hash_impl4hashEPKvmm[_ZNSt10_Hash_impl4hashEPKvmm]+0x27): undefined reference to '_Hash_bytes'
```

do i need to include any library for '_Hash_bytes'?

Comment: What architecture are you compiling for? What system are you running? Does other C++ functions work? Can you post a compilable [MCVE]? What is that `declaration :`  doing in you code snipped? What gcc version do you have? What glibc version do you have? What libstdc++ version do you use?

Comment: You might have a library mismatch (headers for one library version and linking to a different version), but there are also a number of other possibilities. A [mre] would be helpful for ruling things out. *Hint: since hashing seems to be involved, see if you can replace your map's type with something simpler, like `unordered_map<string, int>` while retaining the linker error.*

Comment: I had similar problem and it was the order of libs in the linker